# apache rewrite rule has no get parameters

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^product/(.*?)/.*\.html$ /product.php?sku=$1 [L,QSA]
```

so as it looks when I go to a page -->

```
/product/something/doesntMatterHere.html
```

it will be redirected to -->

```
    /product.php?sku=something
```

but as I check in my code I dont get any GET variables.

BUT, when I go to the url -->

```
/product/something/doesntMatterHere.html?var1=something2
```

so in my GET variable I see -->

```
$_GET['var1'] = 'something2'
```

so the rewrite works, but the get disappears, any ideas?

Comment: You can try this one `^product/([^/]+)/.*\.html$`, it might be (.*?) problem since asterisk is already zero or more and you try to make it optional with question mark

Comment: the rule works... it simply doesnt give me the get variable

Answer (score 0):

Try the followging

Replace

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*?)/.*\.html$ /product.php?sku=$1 [L,QSA]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ product.php?sku=$1 [L,QSA]
```